# Parse escaped JSON in PHP

Tags: java, php, json, parsing, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm a newb in PHP world and I've problems parsing JSON in PHP. I want to POST data to PHP script with my Java client using `Apache HttpClient 4.x` and `Gson`.

My JSON:

```
[{"Knt_KntWatchId":"15","type":"INSERT","Knt_Nazwa1":"a"},{...},...]
```

I'm sending it with Java using `HttpClient` and `Gson`:

```
    List<Contact> contacts = ...;
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(CONTACTS_SERVICE);
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", AppConstants.KEY));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", new Gson().toJson(contacts)));
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
```

On page:

```
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $json = json_decode($data, true);
    var_dump($json);
    var_dump($data);
```

What I'm getting is:

```
NULL string(3651) "[{\"Knt_KntWatchId\":\"15\",\"type\":\"INSERT\",\"Knt_Nazwa1\":\"a\"},...
```

How can I get it working?

PHP 5.2 - can't use `json_last_error()`

Comment: if you're using php 5.2, then you have a problem. It is no longer supported. A number of security issues have been fixed in 5.3 that are still present in 5.2, so you're basically using insecure software on your public-facing systems. Time to upgrade, my friend.

Comment: it's hard to be sure what the problem is. The portion of the json string you've provided looks good, but I'd need to see the whole think. It would only take one mis-matched bracket, quote or comma to throw the whole thing out. Can't see any in the code you showed us, but that doesn't mean it's not there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try with [stripslashes()](http://uk.php.net/stripslashes)

```
$string = stripslashes('[{\"Knt_KntWatchId\":\"15\",\"type\":\"INSERT\",\"Knt_Nazwa1\":\"a\"}]');
print_r(json_decode($string));
```

so il will be

```
$json = json_decode(stripslashes($data), true);
```