# Parse strange json string in php into js

Tags: javascript, php, json, xml

How can I parse a string, like the following that I got from the API response:

```
"{\"response\":\"data\"}"
```

I need the "data" from the "response".

How can do that in PHP or in JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is a JSON string with quotations escaped. In JS, you can parse it using `JSON.parse(myJsonString);`

```js
console.log(JSON.parse("{\"response\":\"data\"}").response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a possible duplicate of [Parse escaped JSON in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210398/parse-escaped-json-in-php)

First we need to remove the escape char `\` using [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php):

```
$input = "{\"response\":\"data\"}";
$input = stripslashes($input);
```

Then you can insert the content into an array using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with second parameter `true` (so you get an array instead of an object):

```
$input = json_decode($input,true);
```

So in a single line:

```
$input = json_decode(stripslashes($input),true);
```

You can access data and response as:

```
$input['data']; $input['response']
```

It is not clear if you need to do this in js or php. The above is the php solution.

Comment: The escaped quotes usually mean that the it was doubly-encoded, so you just need to decode it twice.

Comment: thx,  it is working

Comment: Good. If it works, please feel free to accept the answer.